# cannot link image in HTML/CSS/REACT stored locally on computer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was doing an end to end project -> Movie Recommendation, backend server - Python FLASK, frontend - React.Js, so far it is working good but I cannot link my image which is stored inside a folder. Here are some screenshots.
(I'm inside Movies.js)
Directory:

[image]

The Code:

[image]

And finally, the output of console.log(image) in inspector console to ensure that the image name is correct:

[image]

I have tried adding require("./movie_posters/movie_name....") but no luck.
I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the all "movie_posters" folder to the public folder, you can access it by using "/movie_posters/${YOUR_IMAGE_NAME}" in the image src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing require, import the image before rendering it.

```
const image = require("./movie_poster/"+ ... )
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck again :/
Although when i console.log(image), it returns an object: 
Object { default: "/static/media/Iron_Man_2.b53177d1.jpg", … }